# How do i set X-CSRFToken header with Axios instance in Next.js App?

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios

I want to pass the CSRF token (which currently is a cookie) as a default header in my Axios instance, like this:

```js
export const BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

const api = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
    },
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    timeout: 3000,
    withCredentials: true
});
```

With a getCookie function i found here on StackOverflow:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  if (!document.cookie) {
    return null;
  }

    const xsrfCookies = document.cookie.split(';')
        .map(c => c.trim())
        .filter(c => c.startsWith(name + '='));

    if (xsrfCookies.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(xsrfCookies[0].split('=')[1]);
}
```

But this just results in

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

How can i make sure document is defined? Or is there a better way to do this?

I tried `'use client'` at the top of the file, but it did nothing.
I also tried:

```js
xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
```

EDIT: Works if i put `withXSRFToken: true,` aswell

Comment: It works! I just used `withXSRFToken: true` aswell as the other xsrf options.